# How do you enable mass assignments for mongoid in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Normally you would use something like `attr_accessible :name, :email` to allow for mass assignment for those specific fields but how do you do this in mongoid for an embedded document like `:nick_names`?  I tried tagging it at the end of `attr_accesible` but it does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you remove `attr_accessible` (thus making all fields mass-assignable)?

Comment: Did you try `accept_nested_attributes_for :nicknames`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a combination of criteria and update all.  For instance:

```
Foo.where(country: nil).update_all(country: "USA")
```

http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/modification.html

If you're trying to do it via a Rails update, then @apneadiving is correct in that you need to enable `accept_nested_attributes_for` in the parent model.